Find consecutive non-NA values rowwise up to a specific column under additional conditions
I have this sample data frame
df <- data.frame(New=c("X2", "k 5, N 8", "N30","k 6, N 3", "K5", "S12", "K5", "k 1, N 18"),
  K_10=c(NA, NA, 3, 4,0,2,NA, NA), 
  K_11=c(NA, NA, NA, 4,0,3,NA, NA), 
  K_12=c(NA, 2, NA, NA,0,NA,NA,0), 
  K_13=c(0, 3, 5, NA,0,5,NA,NA), 
  K_14=c(NA, 3, 1, 2,10,10,NA,NA),
  K_15=c(NA, 2, 3, 5,15,10,NA,2),
  K_16=c(NA, 10, 1, 6,43,10,NA,56),
  K_17=c(NA, 5, 1, 3,1,10,NA,23),
  K_18=c(NA, 6, 4, 2,0,10,NA,12),
  K_19=c(NA, 3, 8, NA,3,10,NA,90),
  K_20=c(NA, 3, 19, 2,6,10,NA,59),
  K_21=c(NA, 3, 10, 2,8,10,NA,11),
  K_22=c(NA, 3, NA, 2,9,10,NA,10),
  K_23=c(NA, 3, NA, 2,90,10,NA,9))

df
        New K_10 K_11 K_12 K_13 K_14 K_15 K_16 K_17 K_18 K_19 K_20 K_21 K_22 K_23
1        X2   NA   NA   NA    0   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
2  k 5, N 8   NA   NA    2    3    3    2   10    5    6    3    3    3    3    3
3       N30    3   NA   NA    5    1    3    1    1    4    8   19   10   NA   NA
4  k 6, N 3    4    4   NA   NA    2    5    6    3    2   NA    2    2    2    2
5        K5    0    0    0    0   10   15   43    1    0    3    6    8    9   90
6       S12    2    3   NA    5   10   10   10   10   10   10   10   10   10   10
7        K5   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
8 k 1, N 18   NA   NA    0   NA   NA    2   56   23   12   90   59   11   10    9

I want to create a column that will check rowwise if there are

at most 5 consecutive Non-NAs
between 2 and 5 consecutive Non-NAs

from K_11 up to K_18.
Finally, I want to  create a column that will check if there are at most 5 consecutive Non-NAs from K_11 up to K_18, only when column New takes the values that contain the repeated structure "k N", that is, for the rows "k 5, N 8", "k 6, N 3" and  "k 1, N 18"
So I am looking something like that
        New K_10 K_11 K_12 K_13 K_14 K_15 K_16 K_17 K_18 K_19 K_20 K_21 K_22 K_23 At_most_5 Between_2_5          New_S
1        X2   NA   NA   NA    0   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA      TRUE       FALSE Not Applicable
2  k 5, N 8   NA   NA    2    3    3    2   10    5    6    3    3    3    3    3     FALSE       FALSE          FALSE
3       N30    3   NA   NA    5    1    3    1    1    4    8   19   10   NA   NA     FALSE       FALSE Not Applicable
4  k 6, N 3    4    4   NA   NA    2    5    6    3    2   NA    2    2    2    2      TRUE        TRUE           TRUE
5        K5    0    0    0    0   10   15   43    1    0    3    6    8    9   90     FALSE       FALSE Not Applicable
6       S12    2    3   NA    5   10   10   10   10   10   10   10   10   10   10     FALSE       FALSE Not Applicable
7        K5   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA     FALSE       FALSE Not Applicable
8 k 1, N 18   NA   NA    0   NA   NA    2   56   23   12   90   59   11   10    9      TRUE        TRUE           TRUE

My real data set contains thousands of rows.

A dplyr solution:
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(N = with(rle(is.na(c_across(K_11:K_18))),
                  if(all(values)) 0 else max(lengths[!values])),
         At_most_5 = between(N, 1, 5),
         Between_2_5 = between(N, 2, 5),
         New_S = if_else(grepl("k [0-9]+, N [0-9]+", New),
                         as.character(Between_2_5), "Not applicable")) %>%
  ungroup()

# # A tibble: 8 × 19
#   New        K_10  K_11  K_12  K_13  K_14  K_15  K_16  K_17  K_18  K_19  K_20  K_21  K_22  K_23     N At_most_5 Between_2_5 New_S         
#   <chr>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <lgl>     <lgl>       <chr>         
# 1 X2           NA    NA    NA     0    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     1 TRUE      FALSE       Not applicable
# 2 k 5, N 8     NA    NA     2     3     3     2    10     5     6     3     3     3     3     3     7 FALSE     FALSE       FALSE         
# 3 N30           3    NA    NA     5     1     3     1     1     4     8    19    10    NA    NA     6 FALSE     FALSE       Not applicable
# 4 k 6, N 3      4     4    NA    NA     2     5     6     3     2    NA     2     2     2     2     5 TRUE      TRUE        TRUE          
# 5 K5            0     0     0     0    10    15    43     1     0     3     6     8     9    90     8 FALSE     FALSE       Not applicable
# 6 S12           2     3    NA     5    10    10    10    10    10    10    10    10    10    10     6 FALSE     FALSE       Not applicable
# 7 K5           NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     0 FALSE     FALSE       Not applicable
# 8 k 1, N 18    NA    NA     0    NA    NA     2    56    23    12    90    59    11    10     9     4 TRUE      TRUE        TRUE

You can also transform the data to long format and then summarise it by groups. This approach may take less time than a rowwise operation.
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_longer(K_11:K_18) %>%
  summarise(N = with(rle(is.na(value)), if(all(values)) 0 else max(lengths[!values])),
            At_most_5 = between(N, 1, 5), Between_2_5 = between(N, 2, 5),
            .by = id) %>%
  select(-id) %>% bind_cols(df, .) %>%
  mutate(New_S = if_else(grepl("k [0-9]+, N [0-9]+", New),
                         as.character(Between_2_5), "Not applicable"))


Note that column "New" cannot hold both "character" and logical TRUE/FALSE values. So it contains the character strings "TRUE" and "FALSE" instead of the logical constants TRUE and FALSE.
df_N <- data.frame(New=c("X2", "k 5, N 8", "N30","k 6, N 3", "K5", "S12", "K5", "k 1, N 18"),
    K_10=c(NA, NA, 3, 4,0,2,NA, NA), 
    K_11=c(NA, NA, NA, 4,0,3,NA, NA), 
    K_12=c(NA, 2, NA, NA,0,NA,NA,0), 
    K_13=c(0, 3, 5, NA,0,5,NA,NA), 
    K_14=c(NA, 3, 1, 2,10,10,NA,NA),
    K_15=c(NA, 2, 3, 5,15,10,NA,2),
    K_16=c(NA, 10, 1, 6,43,10,NA,56),
    K_17=c(NA, 5, 1, 3,1,10,NA,23),
    K_18=c(NA, 6, 4, 2,0,10,NA,12),
    K_19=c(NA, 3, 8, NA,3,10,NA,90),
    K_20=c(NA, 3, 19, 2,6,10,NA,59),
    K_21=c(NA, 3, 10, 2,8,10,NA,11),
    K_22=c(NA, 3, NA, 2,9,10,NA,10),
    K_23=c(NA, 3, NA, 2,90,10,NA,9))

#want to create a column that will check rowwise if there are at most
#5 consecutive Non-NAs from K_11 up to K_18.
At_most_5 <- apply(subset(df_N, select = K_11:K_18), 1, function(row) 
  with(rle(is.na(row)), length(which(values == FALSE)) > 0 
                        && max(lengths[values==FALSE]) <= 5))


#I want to create a column that will check rowwise 
#if there are between 2 and 5 consecutive Non-NAs from K_11 up to K_18.
Between_2_5 <- apply(subset(df_N, select = K_11:K_18), 1, function(row) 
  with(rle(is.na(row)), length(which(values==FALSE)) > 0 
                        && max(lengths[values==FALSE]) %in% 2:5 ))

#Finally, I want to create a column that will check if there are 
#at most 5 consecutive Non-NAs from K_11 up to K_18, 
#only when column New takes the values that contain the repeated structure 
#"k N", that is, for the rows "k 5, N 8", "k 6, N 3" and "k 1, N 18"
New_S <- ifelse(grepl("k [0-9]*, N [0-9]*", df_N$New), At_most_5, "Not applicable")

df_N <- cbind(df_N, data.frame(At_most_5, Between_2_5, New_S))

df_N
#>         New K_10 K_11 K_12 K_13 K_14 K_15 K_16 K_17 K_18 K_19 K_20 K_21 K_22
#> 1        X2   NA   NA   NA    0   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
#> 2  k 5, N 8   NA   NA    2    3    3    2   10    5    6    3    3    3    3
#> 3       N30    3   NA   NA    5    1    3    1    1    4    8   19   10   NA
#> 4  k 6, N 3    4    4   NA   NA    2    5    6    3    2   NA    2    2    2
#> 5        K5    0    0    0    0   10   15   43    1    0    3    6    8    9
#> 6       S12    2    3   NA    5   10   10   10   10   10   10   10   10   10
#> 7        K5   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
#> 8 k 1, N 18   NA   NA    0   NA   NA    2   56   23   12   90   59   11   10
#>   K_23 At_most_5 Between_2_5          New_S
#> 1   NA      TRUE       FALSE Not applicable
#> 2    3     FALSE       FALSE          FALSE
#> 3   NA     FALSE       FALSE Not applicable
#> 4    2      TRUE        TRUE           TRUE
#> 5   90     FALSE       FALSE Not applicable
#> 6   10     FALSE       FALSE Not applicable
#> 7   NA     FALSE       FALSE Not applicable
#> 8    9      TRUE        TRUE           TRUE

